# Question about operations that mix numeric types in Go

Tags: go, constants, typechecking

I know that Go is a statically typed language that doesn't allow operations that mix numeric types, for example, you can't add an `int` to a `float64`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
        var a int = 1
        var b float64 = 1.1
        fmt.Println(a + b)
}
```

Running this program will cause an error:

> invalid operation: a + b (mismatched types int and float64)

But when I do the math `1 + 1.1` without declaring the variables, the program returns the desired result which is `2.1`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
        fmt.Println(1 + 1.1)
}
```

So my question is: Why does `1 + 1.1` work? What's the numeric type of `1` and `1.1` when I use them directly in the addition?

Comment: `1 + 1.1` is evaluated as a constant expression. See https://tour.golang.org/basics/15 and https://go.dev/blog/constants .  Doing the whole Tour of Go  **really** is worth the two hours and much simpler than guessing and experimenting.

Comment: Thanks Volker, I do go thru the Tour of Go, it does explain what constant is and how to declare constant using const keyword, but it doesn't mention that something like "1 + 1.1" is evaluated as an untyped constant, that's why I come to StackOverflow for help.  Anyway, thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @Volker, this is because `1 + 1.1` is evaluated as an untyped constant expression.

So below program also works because now `a` and `b` are both untyped constant.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
        const a = 1
        const b = 1.1
        fmt.Println(a + b)
}
```